# Extract Program Counter (Instruction Pointer) in signal handler (ppc64)

Tags: c, linux, assembly, powerpc

In a signal handler under Linux, one has access to the saved context (all register values) of the suspended thread. These register values are obviously architecture dependent. For example, for a PowerPC Little Endian (ppcle) architecture, **ucontext->uc_regs->gp_regs** is an array that contains the values of the general purpose registers.

For certain architectures there are also defines (e.g., the REG_XXX defines for x86-64) which identify the purpose of the registers. For ppc64le such definitions are missing. How can I figure out which registers are which? The little IBM documentation available did not help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of this being documented anywhere.  However,  [`setup_sigcontext`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/powerpc/kernel/signal_64.c#L94) for ppc64 fills in the `gp_regs` array from a [struct `pt_regs`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/powerpc/include/uapi/asm/ptrace.h#L32) that forms part of the task state. Therefore, that struct can be taken as a guide for which registers are which.  There is also a set of `PT_Rxxx` defines immediately below the definition of that struct, which confirms bits of the mapping that are not immediately obvious from the struct (e.g. general purpose register 1 is indeed in gp_regs[1]).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I somehow missed finding the pt_regs structure and it looks like it's the best documentation on the ppc64 registers. Unfortunately, it does not help explain the purpose of some of the registers (GPS included). I guess that I can use the registers names to design a test to find out. It would go something like this: 1) call a function; 2) in the function I will dump all register values twice or more using assembler code; 3) deduce which register holds PC by comparing which register has close enough values that are uniformly increasing

Comment: @Radu The numbered slots in the `gp_regs` array are just the numbered general purpose registers, r0 .. r31, with the functions defined by the ABI (e.g. r1 is the stack pointer and r2 is the TOC pointer).  Of the named fields in the struct, `ctr`, `link`, `xer`, `ccr`, `softe`, `mq`, `dar`, and `dsisr` correspond to named registers in the architecture manual, and `orig_gpr3`, `trap`, and `result` are labeled with their function.  That leaves only `nip` to be the PC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Makes sense now and seems like I have all that I needed.